# X n. of columns with ul li but keep the same order

Tags: html, css

Right now there is only two columns needed, eventually there, may be a third column or more.

```
<ul>
  <li class="c1">1</li>
  <li class="c1">3</li>
  <li class="c1">2</li>
  <li class="c2">4</li>
  <li class="c1">5</li>
  <li class="c2">6</li>
  <li class="c2">7</li>
  <li class="c1">8</li>
</ul>
```

The order on that list is the correct order, now we need two columns as per the `c1` and `c2` class.
my css is something like this.

```
ul {
 margin:0; padding:0;
 list-style: none;
 column:2;
 li {
  float: left;
 }
}
```

with that basic CSS I'm getting the two columns but not the correct amount.

```
------------
|  1  |  5 |
|  3  |  6 |
|  2  |  7 |
|  4  |  8 |
------------
```

You might say, well, what's the problem there you have your two columns, yes and nop, what's needed is the following.

```
------------
|  1  |  4 |
|  3  |  6 |
|  2  |  7 |
|  5  |    |
|  8  |    |
------------
```

I could use the `li:nth-child(x)` and `break` it after Xn li but not always is the same, now I was thinking to use class `c1` as `float left` and `c2` for `float right`, but what if there are `c3` which could mean a third column or `c4`.
I have try bootstrap `d-flex`, `col`, `order` but is not working for this.
I'm not good with CSS to do this and I prefer not use JavaScript but if there is no solution with only CSS then I'm gonna explore that option, last and the easiest way is to re-do the array output and make the 2 or 3 or xn array(blocks) per column, which mean increasing the number of line code.
Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [`display: grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) might be suitable for the desired layout. If there is a `c3` class later, it just need to have `grid-column: 3` set to be placed in the third column.

Example:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}

.c1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.c2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="c1">1</li>
  <li class="c1">3</li>
  <li class="c1">2</li>
  <li class="c2">4</li>
  <li class="c1">5</li>
  <li class="c2">6</li>
  <li class="c2">7</li>
  <li class="c1">8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yep, I need to study more CSS, this was simple, thanks.

Comment: is there a way to prevent the gap, see, the first column all items have two lines, but for items on the second column each item is one line, so, say, items on the right column has the same height as the one on the left. I have try using height, margin but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tanker Not sure, but maybe we could try figure it out if there is a code example of the situation.